# Exclude some elements from .html(); in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a link with a text, a `linebreak` and a image inside.

```
<a title="title" href="#" class="mail">info@domain.de
  <br><img src="img/icons/icon.png">
</a>
```

So to get all together inside the anchor I use:

```
$('.mail').html();
```

Now I want to exclude this only to get info@domain.de:

```
<br><img src="img/icons/icon.png">
```

---

### Example

```js
$('.mail').html();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a title="title" href="#" class="mail">info@domain.de
   <br><img src="img/icons/icon.png">
</a>
```

How should I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to get just the text for the `<a>` tag

```js
var text = $('.mail').text();
console.log(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a title="title" href="#" class="mail">info@domain.de
   <br><img src="img/icons/icon.png">
</a>
```

Comment: As allways Master Yoda tells the truth. Thank you this works.

Comment: Always two there are, no more, no less. A master and an apprentice. :)

Answer (score 3):

In this specific case, if you just want the *text*, use [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) instead of `html` (perhaps with [`.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) or [`$.trim(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/)):

```js
console.log($('.mail').text().trim());
```

```html
<a title="title" href="#" class="mail">info@domain.de
   <br><img src="img/icons/icon.png">
</a>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In the general case, though, if there are elements you want to include and others you want to exclude in this kind of situation, you can make a [`clone`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) and [`remove`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) them:

```js
console.log(
  $('.mail').clone()
    .find("br, img").remove()
    .end()
    .html()
);
```

```html
<a title="title" href="#" class="mail">info@domain.de
   <br><img src="img/icons/icon.png">
   <span>Suppose you wanted this span but not the <code>br<code> or <code>img</code>.</span>
</a>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.text()` instead of `.html()`

```js
$('.mail').text();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a title="title" href="#" class="mail">info@domain.de
   <br><img src="img/icons/icon.png">
</a>
```